# Why is my XInput gamepad press stamp not working?

Tags: c++, directx, input, gamepad

I'm trying to add basic gamepad input to my c++ DirectX game but i'm having some trouble creating a press stamp (registers the press only the first time it's pressed if button held down).

The entire input class is here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/28be899570c72fe7ae98

My ButtonPressed function:

```
bool Input::wasGamePadButtonPressed(int padNum, WORD button)
{
    if((gamepad[padNum].wButtons & button) & 
        ((gamepad[padNum].wButtons & button) != (prevGamepadState[padNum].wButtons & button)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The It's just as basic press stamp, if the button is down, and the button was not down before, return true, else return false.

In my input::strobe() i strobe all the inputs and collect their states. at the beginning of the strobe i copy the current states and save them to a previous states structure

```
void Input::strobe(void)
{
    //hold on to the previous states for input stamping
    memcpy(prevKeys, keys, sizeof(keys));
    memcpy(prevGamepadState, gamepad, sizeof(gamepad));

    //gather keyboard
    HRESULT err;
    err = keyboard->GetDeviceState(sizeof(keys), (LPVOID) &keys);
    if((err == DIERR_INPUTLOST )|| (err == DIERR_NOTACQUIRED))
    {
        keyboard->Acquire();
    }

    //gather mouse
    err = mouse->GetDeviceState(sizeof(mouse_state), (LPVOID) &mouse_state);
    if((err == DIERR_INPUTLOST )|| (err == DIERR_NOTACQUIRED))
    {
        mouse->Acquire();
    }

    //strobe controllers
    if(hasGamepads)
    {
        for(int ii = 0; ii < 4; ii++)
        {
            ZeroMemory(&gamepad[ii], sizeof(XINPUT_STATE));
            XINPUT_STATE state;
            DWORD result = XInputGetState(ii, &state);

            if(result == 0)
            {
                gamepad[ii] = state.Gamepad;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine for my keyboard press stamp, which is very similar to the gamepad press function, but the game pad one refuses to work for some reason, firing true every frame for as long as i hold down the button.

It seems really straight forward so i cannot think of why it't not working. the only thing i can think is an issue in the strober, which i did not write originally (most of the basic directinput stuff was given in a class i took), or its me misunderstanding bitwise masks and I've got that gamepadpressed function totally wrong.

Comment: What values can "button" have, specifically?

Comment: these in the XINPUT_GAMEPAD structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.xinput_gamepad(v=vs.85).aspx they're bitmasks

Comment: One thing to remember about XInputGetState is that it's a non-buffering polling API. If you don't call it fast enough, you may miss 'stamps'. BTW, I see you are using DirectInput for keyboard and mouse. It is strongly recommended that you make use of standard Win32 messages instead for keyboard & mouse. DirectInput should be used only for legacy HID controllers (ala joysticks and the like).